# Understanding async with WebClient UploadString() vs UploadStringTaskAsync

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, async-await

I'm struggling to understand the benefits of async vs sync, when it runs in a non-visual context, e.g. an Azure Worker or a Web Api controller:

```
using (var wc = new WebClient())
{
    wc.UploadString(uri, message);
    // vs.
    await wc.UploadStringTaskAsync(uri, message);
}
```

Doesn't the main thread need to wait anyway and hence it makes no difference for performance? What else is there apart from UI jobs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's true that even if you're using `async` there is some main thread running somewhere. The benefits are that you can have multiple asynchronous operations concurrently without blocking any threads. That increases your scalability since you can handle more work with less resources.

Imagine that instead of a single `WebClient` you're using 1000. There is still a main thread somewhere, but instead of blocking 1000 threads more on IO, you are using none.

```
public Task Upload(string message)
{
    using (var wc = new WebClient())
    {
        wc.UploadString(uri, message);
        // vs.
        await wc.UploadStringTaskAsync(uri, message);
    }
}

await Task.WhenAll(messages.Select(message => Upload(message))) // multiple operations. 0 blocked threads.
```

Comment: That means with a single operation and no additional threads created it does not make a difference, right?

Comment: @BenjaminE. If your whole application needs only 1 thread and responsiveness is not an issue then yes, there's no real difference. But most applications, especially server applications, don't use just a single thread.

Comment: OK, given a Wep Api controller which uses one instance per request, does async yield any resources back to the threadpool or does this controller instance hold onto the thread anyway?

Comment: As @YuvalItzchakov said, you are giving a thread from the thread pool to handle the request which is returned if not needed by the `async` operation. There's still may be a thread somewhere waiting for new requests though.

Answer (score 5):

> Doesn't the main thread need to wait anyway and hence it makes no
>   difference for performance? What else is there apart from UI jobs?

When you're using Web API for example, the ASP.NET threadpool gives you a thread which you execute your code on. When you `await` an asynchronous method, you're releasing that thread back to the pool to allow more connections to be processed. The async method yields control back to the calling method (or if its a top level handler, to the threadpool) and now that thread is free to process more work. While in the synchronous version, you're simply blocking the thread until the IO completes.

That way, even though there's no UI involved, you keep your app more responsive in the manner that lets you process more work concurrently.